# JSDoc 3 template?

Tags: ecmascript-6

JSDoc 3 master seems to be useful for ES6 at this point, ref.
[ECMAScript 6 documentation generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334309/ecmascript-6-documentation-generators/29443693#29443693).

However the default template has source code rendering issues (syntax highlighting, line numbering), a class list hierarchy would be useful also, etc.

Can anyone suggest a template that is more release ready?

[Edit]

`[Symbol.iterator]()` generator functions are not parsing by the looks, issue opened https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/555#issuecomment-89656059

[Edit[

The bug to watch for a fix for this https://github.com/eslint/espree/issues/123

Comment: Some of the major players: 
minami http://npmjs.com/package/minami, 
DocStrap https://github.com/terryweiss/docstrap,
jsdoc3Template https://github.com/danyg/jsdoc3Template,
Jaguar.js https://github.com/davidshimjs/jaguarjs-jsdoc, essentially themes though, none with a class list hierarchy.

Comment: Automatically generating links to external JS documentation is a feature often implemented by doc. generators also (Date / Array types, etc.).

Comment: You can also use: [github.com/clenemt/docdash](https://github.com/clenemt/docdash)

Comment: checkout https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/better-docs